# Finding exceptions address

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-xe2, memory-address

I have two related questions when it comes to finding the offset in an application where an exception occurred.

The first is about the calculation I use to find the offset which is:

`Offset = ExceptionAddress - $00400000 - $1000`

I know the `$00400000` is the image base found in the linker settings, but where does the `$1000` come from? Is it always `$1000`?

The second question is about the resulting offset when using the above calculation with an exception address of `001BD81F`. The calculation leaves an offset of `FFFFFFFFFFDBC81F`. This appears to be a negative value and I'm unsure what could cause this, other then a garbage exception address being returned in the first place.

Comment: Install Eurekalog and let it do the work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Delphi map file reports the address of the symbol relative to the start of the segment containing it. The start of the map file looks like this:

```
 Start         Length     Name                   Class
 0001:00401000 00AD87A4H .text                   CODE
```

That is, the CODE segment starts at address `00401000`. Between `00400000` and `00401000` is the PE metadata, I believe.

The subsequent parts of the map file look like this:

```
Detailed map of segments

 0001:00000000 0000E174 C=CODE     S=.text    G=(none)   M=System   ACBP=A9
 0001:0000E174 00000734 C=CODE     S=.text    G=(none)   M=SysInit  ACBP=A9
 ....
```

Notice how the address is written. So, `0001:0000E174` means segment `0001`, offset `0000E174` from the start of that segment. Once the module is loaded, the absolute address is formed by taking the segment base address, and adding the offset to the symbol. So the SysInit module starts at `00401000 + 0000E174 = 0040F174`.

In my experience, the linker always places the code segment at the same offset from the module base address. But you don't need to assume that. You can read the information out of the map file.

The address `001BD81F` is in a different module. That is, that address, if it is indeed code, is code from a DLL that your executable loaded. So, you won't be able to find its symbol's in your executable's map file. You would need to first work out which module the address is in, and then find a symbol map for that module.

It is very much easier to use a tool like madExcept, EurekaLog or JclDebug to provide such information. You will get much richer information that way.